# The radiation pattern of two parallel dipoles in out-of phase by $90°$

Tags: radiation, antennas

How can we find the radiation pattern of two identical and parallel dipole antennas which are kept apart by a distance of $\lambda /4$ in the $H$-plane?

**Given:** They are fed with equal currents but the right most antenna has a phase shift of $+90°$.

**My Approach:**
In order to solve this problem, I have invoked Antenna Array Theory.

[image]

Since I have centered the array about the origin, therefore phase factor in $AF$ would not be present.

Now, we know for Vertical plane: 
$$|AF|=|\frac{\sin (\frac{N \psi }{2})}{\sin \frac{\psi}{2}}|,where \quad \psi = \beta d \cos \theta + \alpha
$$
so for horizontal plane $\cos \theta$ will be replaced by $\sin \phi$, that is,
$$
|AF|=\left\lvert\frac{\sin (\frac{N \psi }{2})}{\sin \frac{\psi}{2}}\right\rvert,\quad \text{where} \quad \psi = \beta d \sin \phi + \alpha
$$
and since I have centered the array about origin $\angle AF = 0$, so therefore
\begin{align}
AF& = \left\lvert\frac{\sin (\frac{2 \psi }{2})}{\sin \frac{\psi}{2}}\right\rvert,\quad \text{as} \quad N=2
\\ & = \left\lvert2 \cos \left(\frac{\psi}{2}\right)\right\rvert
\\ & = \left\lvert2 \cos \left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2} \sin \phi + \frac{\pi}{ 2}}{2}\right)\right\rvert
\\ \implies AF & = 2 \left\lvert\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{ 4} \sin \phi + \frac{\pi}{ 4}\right)\right\rvert.
\tag 1
\end{align}
Now, we know that
$$
\text{Resultant pattern} = \text{Unit Pattern} \times \text{Group pattern}.
$$
Since in the question it is not mentioned which dipole antennas are used, I have used here the basic dipole antenna that is Half-wave Dipole Antenna.

Therefore, normalised $|E_s|$ of Half-wave Dipole Antenna:
$$
f(\theta) = \left\lvert\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} \cos \theta)}{\sin \theta}\right\rvert
$$
H-plane pattern of Half-wave dipole antenna can be determined by putting $\theta= \frac{\pi}{2}$ in $f(\theta)$, so therefore the H-plane pattern of Half-wave dipole antenna is $1 \forall \phi$.

Hence, the Resultant Pattern $=$ Group Pattern.

Note: Group Pattern can be obtained from eq. $(1)$, so $2 \left\lvert\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{ 4} \sin \phi + \frac{\pi}{ 4}\right)\right\rvert$:

[image]

But the answer is given as

[image]

So: where is my mistake? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [2-element array theory done here](http://www.gmrt.ncra.tifr.res.in/gmrt_hpage/Users/doc/WEBLF/LFRA/node43.html) it seems to me that this is really equivalent to the analysis of a two source interference pattern?

I think that you heart shaped polar diagram is correct and the "correct" answer that you give is for a phase difference between the antenna of $180^\circ$.

Sometimes no detailed analysis is necessary as I have tried to explain below.

For the far field at angles $\theta = 0^\circ$ and $\theta = 180^\circ$ one could sketch graphs of the E-field waves at an instant of time as shown below.

[image]

You will note that the waves form each of the antennas are $90^\circ$ out of phase with one another because of the phase difference between the two antennas and there is no phase shift due to path difference because at angles $\theta = 0^\circ$ and $\theta = 180^\circ$ the path differences are the same.
If at a fixed position the waves are $E_1= E_0 \sin (\omega t )$ and $E_2= E_0 \sin (\omega t +90^\circ)$ then their sum is $\sqrt 2 E_0\sin(\omega t +45^\circ)$ where $\omega$ is the frequency of the transmission.
This result is at variance with the "correct" answer which shows zeros in these directions.

For angles $\theta = 90^\circ$ and $\theta = 270^\circ$ the electric field waves from the two antennas are as follows.

[image]

Here you will note cancellation in the $\theta = 90^\circ$ direction because the waves from the two antennas are exactly out of phase with one another and in the $\theta = 270^\circ$ direction the waves are in phase with one another resulting in a wave of amplitude $2E_0$.
Again this is not what is shown in the "correct" answer.